# How to fix "connection failed" in Dockerfile accessing MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to package a microservices product into a single container, including all code and the MongoDB database.

Wrote the below dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:3.4-xenial

RUN mkdir -p /opt/xxx

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN apt-get install zip \
    unzip
RUN apt-get update -y && \
apt-get clean

COPY ./xxx-repo/target/xxx-repo.zip /opt/xxx

WORKDIR /opt/xxx 
RUN unzip xxx-repo.zip

# Start MongoDB here
RUN mongod --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath /data/db/ &

RUN echo ' \n\ 
    mongo -- admin <<EOF \n\
    db.createUser({user:"user", pwd:"admin123", roles:[{role:"root", db:"admin"}]}) \n\
EOF ' >> ./init_mongo.sh && chmod +x ./init_mongo.sh && ./init_mongo.sh
```

When I try this, it returns:

```
 ---> Running in 7a21d6fed848
MongoDB shell version v3.4.22
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin
2019-09-10T09:30:51.453+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2019-09-10T09:30:51.457+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:240:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
The command '/bin/sh -c echo ' \n    mongo -- admin <<EOF \n    db.createUser({user:"user", pwd:"admin123", roles:[{role:"root", db:"admin"}]}) \nEOF ' >> ./init_mongo.sh && chmod +x ./init_mongo.sh && ./init_mongo.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How could I start the mongo instance, perhaps wait until the daemon is ready then continue with bringing up my services?​

Comment: what are you trying to do ? that is will not work `RUN mongod --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath /data/db/ &`

Comment: @LinPy
Your "version" would work, if I wanted mongo to run in the foreground e.g. the script would never get to the next step.

Comment: you missed it, I typed not work , any of those will work since it is in the RUN directive in Dockerfile next steps will not have DB running ......

Comment: You should almost always run the application and its data in _separate_ containers.  That avoids this problem.  It also avoids trouble when you update the application and need to delete and recreate its container; you don't also want to restart the database at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not start Mongodb during build stage and if you do so it will not available in next RUN command as each RUN command execute in its own shell.

Move this to cmd

```
# Start MongoDB here
RUN mongod --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath /data/db/ &
```

And add these  line to `.js`  file or bash and run from entrypoint when DB is up better to check offical images entrypoint which deal with import and other stuff too.

```
RUN echo ' \n\ 
    mongo -- admin <<EOF \n\
    db.createUser({user:"user", pwd:"admin123", roles:[{role:"root", db:"admin"}]}) \n\
```

https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/ebd79727e4e77210272ec55c8b22b17877bfd29a/3.4/docker-entrypoint.sh